# add icon menu javafx, but not in a menu item

Tags: javafx

I need to add an icon or an image to a menu within a menu bar.

I managed to add an icon to a menu-item, the way then with CSS javafx:

```css
.search> .label {
     -fx-graphic: url ("../ img / search .png");
}
```

But I can not add an image to a menu that is inside a menu-bar.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a CSS id on the menu, instead of a style class:

```
Menu menu = new Menu("Search");
menu.setId("search");
```

and then

```css
#search > .label {
    -fx-graphic: url(...);
}
```

(And of course you can just do this directly in Java too with `menu.setGraphic(...)`.)

Comment: Thanks was very helpful.